# input errors : split part of one entery

Tags: c++, input, io

i am doing some practice on standard I/O
i have a complex class . my class has overloaded insertion and extraction operators ,the input should of the form : 
x + yi(e.g 10 + 9i) 
i have to determine if input is valid or not . 
there is the problem , if i input in this form the result is always a failbit , 
cause i am inputing a char 'i' to an integer data type . 
so how i can do that , without having a fail bit ? 
mine function is like this :

```
istream &operator>>(istream &input, Complex &complex)
{
    input >> complex.realPart;
    input.ignore(3);
    input >> complex.imaginaryPart;

    return input;
}
```

but this is obviously is not enough !if there was a space between i and integer it could solve every thing . but there is no !i thought of using array , or even string,but then copying them to int private data of my class, does not seem a good programming . and what errors i have to look for after all?? 
thanks a lot ! ;)

Comment: no , complex doesnt matter, I/O is what i want to learn ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check for the '+' and the trailing 'i':

```
istream &operator>>(istream &input, Complex &complex)
{
    char plus,letter;
    if (input >> complex.realPart >> plus)  {
        if (plus!='+' ) 
            input.setstate(ios::failbit);
        else if (input >> complex.imaginaryPart>>letter) {
             if (letter!='i')
                 input.setstate(ios::failbit);
        }
    }
    return input;
}
```

Live [demo here](http://ideone.com/4ayqBK)

Note that you could also make it simpler with teh following:

```
istream &operator>>(istream &input, Complex &complex)
{
    char plus,letter;
    if ( (input >> complex.realPart >> plus >> complex.imaginaryPart>>letter) && (plus!='+' || letter!='i'))
            input.setstate(ios::failbit);
    return input;
}
```

The difference with the previous version is when another letter than plus was provided:  the first version stops immediately to read the input knowing it's anyway wrong, while the second version would continue to consume the stream.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) and [`std::sscanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf) to parse out the values

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string input;
    std::getline(std::cin, input);

    int real;
    int imaginary;
    std::sscanf(input.c_str(), "%i + %ii", &real, &imaginary);
    std::cout << real << " " << imaginary;
}
```

Input

```
5 + 3i
```

Output - [Live Demo](http://cpp.sh/8zk23)

```
5 3
```

The [return value of `std::sscanf` according to cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf) is

> Number of receiving arguments successfully assigned, or EOF if read failure occurs before the first receiving argument was assigned.

So you can check if the return value `== 2` to ensure it was a valid input

Comment: But how would you process `cin >> c1 >> c2;` with all the data on a single line ?  ;-)

Comment: If I was still trying to avoid `operator>>`? `<regex>` :)

Comment: Overloading the `operator>>` is a good method by the way, I was just providing an alternative, and I'm also just being a bit cheeky.

Comment: sscanf is interesting ,'%' is provided for the first character of built in data types?? "%f","%d","%c","%i" ?i think more detail on sscanf , can help the answer ! thank you so much both answers are good ,but first one is closer to what i want !;)

Comment: Look at the table on the [cppreference page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf). They enumerate what each code is, e.g. `%c`, `%s`, etc